# Euclidean distances between several images and one base image

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy

I have a matrix `X` of dimensions `(30x8100)` and another one `Y` of dimensions `(1x8100)`. I want to generate an array containing the difference between them `(X[1]-Y, X[2]-Y,..., X[30]-Y)`
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need for that is

```
X - Y
```

Since several people have offered answers that seem to try to make the shapes match manually, I should explain:
Numpy will automatically expand `Y`'s shape so that it matches with that of `X`.  This is called [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), and it usually does a very good job of guessing what should be done.  In ambiguous cases, an `axis` keyword can be applied to tell it which direction to do things.  Here, since `Y` has a dimension of length 1, that is the axis that is expanded to be length `30` to match with `X`'s shape.

For example,

```
In [87]: import numpy as np

In [88]: n, m = 3, 5

In [89]: x = np.arange(n*m).reshape(n,m)

In [90]: y = np.arange(m)[None,...]

In [91]: x.shape
Out[91]: (3, 5)

In [92]: y.shape
Out[92]: (1, 5)

In [93]: (x-y).shape
Out[93]: (3, 5)

In [106]: x
Out[106]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])

In [107]: y
Out[107]: array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])

In [108]: x-y
Out[108]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 5,  5,  5,  5,  5],
       [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]])
```

But this is not really a euclidean distance, as your title seems to suggest you want:

```
df = np.asarray(x - y)                # the difference between the images
dst = np.sqrt(np.sum(df**2, axis=1))  # their euclidean distances
```

Comment: I am getting `ValueError: input must be a square array
`

Comment: @user2229953 Oh, because your `x` and `y` have type `matrix`, use `np.asarray` so that the squaring will be element-wise, see my edit.

Comment: Thank you ! But the results are wired !
`dst
[ 11368.09117391   7238.28732897   5975.85568237   6516.33956578
   4690.22604361   4727.27377993   5210.6757694    4917.37040654
   4315.19124481   4351.23160123   4219.13923247   4003.55476258
   4175.54212706   4102.91009999   4330.4599796    4184.70386037
   4134.89623796   4162.12512307   3828.49532333   3930.67847956
   3766.93023507   3666.34224248   4040.05576148   3848.65880709
   3845.35577393   3869.77351631   3836.28039808   3801.06876888
   3799.32736535   3646.77473834]`

Comment: @user2229953 Did you have something else in mind?  It makes sense that the shape of `dst` is `(30,)`, because it's how different each image is from the base image.  The units of that 'distance' is basically pixel brightness (assuming grayscale image).  Then, `dst[i]` says how different is the brightness of image `images[i]` from the base (input?) image.  Finding `imin = argmin(dst)` will say `images[imin]` is the most similar image to the input image.

Comment: No. But the final results (getting the most similar image) are wrong and the values looked of `dst` looked wired so I was wondering that there is a relation

Comment: Well, similar to our eyes (and possibly for your application) is not necessarily the same thing as closest in the euclidean distance.  Euclidean distance compares each pixel at a given location, as in, `image1[i,j]` is compared to `image2[i,j]`.  The 'closest' image in euclidean distance is the one for which all these comparisons, in total, are the least.  Note that the same image, rotated by a bit, might be very 'far' in this sense from itself.

Answer (score 1):

use `array` and use `numpy` broadcasting in order to subtract it from `Y`

init the matrix:

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> a = array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

Accessing the second row in `a`:

```
>>> a[1]
array([4, 5, 6])
```

Subtract array from `Y`

```
>>> Y = array([3,9,0])
>>> a - Y

array([[-2, -7,  3],
       [ 1, -4,  6]])
```

Comment: The looping is done automatically by [numpy broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate rows from your numpy array and you can actually just subtract them and numpy will make a new array with the differences!

```
import numpy as np
final_array = []
#X is a numpy array that is 30X8100 and Y is a numpy array that is 1X8100
for row in X:
    output = row - Y
    final_array.append(output)
```

output will be your resulting array of X[0] - Y, X[1] - Y etc. Now your final_array will be an array with 30 arrays inside, each that have the values of the X-Y that you need! Simple as that. Just make sure you convert your matrices to a numpy arrays first

**Edit:** Since numpy broadcasting will do the iteration, all you need is one line once you have your two arrays:

```
final_array = X - Y
```

And then that is your array with the differences!

Comment: The looping is done automatically by [numpy broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Comment: @askewchan Oh, didn't know that...then it's incredibly simple, I made the edits!

Answer (score 0):

```
a1 = numpy.array(X) #make sure you have a numpy array like [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],...]
a2 = numpy.array(Y) #make sure you have a 1d numpy array like [1,2,3,...]
a2 = [a2] * len(a1[0]) #make a2 as wide as a1
a2 = numpy.array(zip(*a2)) #transpose it (a2 is now same shape as a1)

print a1-a2 #idiomatic difference between a1 and a2 (or X and Y)
```

Comment: This `a2 = [a2] * len(a1[0]) #make a2 as wide as a1`  is done automatically by [numpy broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).